# Moveit set_pose_target() weird motions

Tags: moveit, ros-noetic, move-group, trac-ik

I have an ABB IRB 1200 robotic arm that I'm controlling with MoveIt in ROS Noetic.

Using `move_group.set_pose_target(pose)`, I'm getting weird inefficient motions sometimes.
Using `move_group.set_joint_value_target(pose,True)`, I'm ***not*** getting weird motions.

However, obstacle avoidance is only supported using `set_pose_target()`, because it plans in cartesian space.

How can I get the best of both worlds, ie. efficient motions and obstacle avoidance?

#### I tried:

- increasing planning attempts: `move_group.set_num_planning_attempts(20)`

  - didn't work
- increase tolerance: `move_group.set_goal_tolerance(0.01)`

  - weird motions occurred less often.

#### I'm using the Trac solver:

- kinematics_solver: trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin
- kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
- kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
- solve_type: Distance

#### And BiTRRT for path planning:

```
planner_configs:
 BiTRRT:
    type: geometric::BiTRRT
    range: 0.0 
    temp_change_factor: 0.1  
    init_temperature: 100  
    frountier_threshold: 0.0  
    frountier_node_ratio: 0.1  
    cost_threshold: 1e300  

manipulator:
  default_planner_config: BiTRRT
  planner_configs:
    - BiTRRT
    - etc
  projection_evaluator: joints(joint_1,joint_2)
  longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.005
```

Comment: You should be looking at "path planning", not at "inverse kinematics". Typically your moveit config will choose a path planner from the OMPL library. OMPL has many different planners.

Comment: I'm using BiTRRT planner from OMPL lib, with config: 
 BiTRRT:
    type: geometric::BiTRRT
    range: 0.0  #
    temp_change_factor: 0.1 
    init_temperature: 100 
    frountier_threshold: 0.0 
    frountier_node_ratio: 0.1 
    cost_threshold: 1e300

Comment: I have not used this BitRRT planner, but my guess is that you need to set better config values. You can start by reading the two papers mentioned near the top of the .h file: https://github.com/ompl/ompl/blob/main/src/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/BiTRRT.h

Comment: It looks like all OMPL planners result in inefficient joint angels

Comment: Let's make sure we discussing the same problem: A) are you saying that the path that the eef is following is not good, or B) are you saying that the eef path is ok but the motion of the intermediate joints is not nice? How many DOF does the arm have (not including the manipulator)?

Comment: 6 DOF. Both A and B are non optimal in the case of the weird motions. When I check the final joint angles (angles plan[1].joint_trajectory.points[-1].positions) of the plan=move_group.plan() in these cases, the joint angles are a valid IK solution, but far from the most optimal one. When I calculate an IK solution using roboticstooblox in these cases, and use MotionPlanning in Rviz ( with collision aware IK) and the joint angels set to the IK solution it works fine and as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments indicate you are unhappy with both the path planning and the IK solver.

You can get this `move_group` software to work better, but it will require more effort on your part. Remember that this is generic solver code, so it has no idea what you consider optimal or what might work better for your particular robot arm or for your particular application.

If it were me, I'd focus on the eef path planning first. Many planners try to minimize path length, but you may have to tell it to look for improvements rather than returning the first solution it finds. It is also usually necessary to tune the planner's parameters for your application. As an advanced feature, `move_group` also has support for Path Constraints and Joint Constraints, which are useful in some situations.

Don't ignore the fact that your code can use pre-defined solutions for some paths or some goal poses. It's way faster and deterministic if your code  doesn't need to explore the search space.